# LUIS ActionBinding Param Library doesnt display if enum

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

If I specify as enum then it doesn't get displayed in the dialog. Can anyone help to point out if am missing some thing?

```
        [LuisActionBinding("CollPay", FriendlyName = "Reminder")]
        public class CollPayAction : BaseLuisAction
        {

            public enum PaymentAmtOptions
            {
                [Terms(new string[] { "Full Payment", "Entire Amount", "Full Due Amount" })]
                FullPayment = 1,

                [Terms(new string[] { "Clubbed Payment", "Combined Payment" })]
                CombinedPayment
            };

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Are you planning to make a separate payment or combined one?")]
            [LuisActionBindingParam(CustomType = "BOPYMTOPTION", Order = 2)]
            [Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Are you planning to make a separate payment or combined one? {||}",
                              "How would you like to make the payment - separate for each Invoice(or) clubbed with other pending dues? {||}")]
            public PaymentAmtOptions PaymentAmount { get; set; }


            public override Task<object> FulfillAsync()
            {
                var result = string.Format("Hello! You have reached the CollPay intent");

                return Task.FromResult((object)result);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it was certainly an issue. The good news is that a [PR with a patch](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/127) was already created.

Once the PR is approved, you will have to update your code:

-To use the updated library
 -To validate the enum value. Below you will find how the code could look like:

```
[LuisActionBinding("CollPay", FriendlyName = "Reminder")]
public class CollPayAction : BaseLuisAction
{
    public enum PaymentAmtOptions
    { 
        None = 0,   // default - no option selected
        FullPayment = 1,
        CombinedPayment = 2
    };

    // custom validator for my enum value
    public class ValidPaymentAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return value is PaymentAmtOptions &&  ((PaymentAmtOptions)value) != PaymentAmtOptions.None;
        }
    }

    [ValidPayment(ErrorMessage = "Are you planning to make a separate payment [FullPayment] or combined one [CombinedPayment]?")]
    [LuisActionBindingParam(CustomType = "BOPYMTOPTION", Order = 2)]
    public PaymentAmtOptions PaymentAmount { get; set; }

    public override Task<object> FulfillAsync()
    {
        var result = string.Format("Hello! You have reached the CollPay intent");

        return Task.FromResult((object)result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I will try now.

Comment: I don't think the PR was merged yet but you can take the fixes. Please mark as answered